# How can I apply multiple filter using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I apply multiple filter using pandas for 100 values easily?
There are two columns (column/column2), and 500000 rows.
My aim is: find some values such as value-1, value-2, etc. in the sample.xlsx file (should be include all of them). Then extract unique values from column2 to another xlsx file.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
filtered_list = df[(df['column']=='value-1')|
                   (df['column']=='value-2')]
                   (df['column']=='value-3')]
                   .......
                   (df['column']=='value-100')]
print(filtered_list)
```

```
    list = ['value-1', 'value-2', ..., 'value-100']
    **Sample Dataset**
    column      column2
    value-1     gene1
    value-2     gene1
    value-3     gene2
    value-4     gene2
    value-5     gene2
    .....       ....
    value-100   gene3
    value-102   gene3
    value-105   gene4
```

```
**1. Desired Output**
column      column2
value-1     gene1
value-2     gene1
value-3     gene2
value-4     gene2
value-5     gene2
.....       ....
value-100   gene3
```

```
**2. Desired Output**
column2
gene1
gene2
gene3
```

@domiziano

Comment: Can you please provide a dataset input sample and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all the values you want you can do

```
list = ['value-1', 'value-2', ..., 'value-100']

filtered_list = df[df['column'].isin(list)]
```

Then to see all unique values from column2

```
filtered_list['column2'].unique()
```

Comment: Thank you @eduardoftdo. Then how can I extract unique values from column2?

Comment: If after filtering you want to see all unique values from column2 try filtered_list['column2'].unique()